# Scala Map with mutable default value always point to the same object

Tags: scala, data-structures, mutable

Scala version:3.1

I want to create a String -> Int map, that each key may point to many Int.

Therefore I choose map with default mutable `Buffer[Int]`.

But it seems the all the keys always point to the same `Buffer[Int]`

Notice it is also weird in the first  `m("a") += 1` that, it print out nothing after this `+=` but default value changed so that it print **two 1**   in the next `println`.

Also, how I can fix the problem that `mutable.Map`'s `+=` is overriden by `Buffer`'s `+=`. I am expecting the map insert a new `Buffer` if the key doens't exist, then call `+=` of the `buffer`.

```
  import scala.collection.mutable
  val m: mutable.Map[String, mutable.Buffer[Int]] =
    mutable.HashMap.empty.withDefaultValue(mutable.Buffer.empty)

  m("a") += 1
  println(m) // Map()

  m("a") = m("a") += 1

  println(m) // Map(a -> ArrayBuffer(1, 1))

  m("b") = m("b") += 2 // Map(a -> ArrayBuffer(1, 1, 2), b -> ArrayBuffer(1, 1, 2)) , not expecting this, key is correct but

  println(m) // Map(a -> ArrayBuffer(1, 1, 2), b -> ArrayBuffer(1, 1, 2))

  m("a") = m("a") += 2

  println(m) // Map(a -> ArrayBuffer(1, 1, 2, 2), b -> ArrayBuffer(1, 1, 2, 2)) , 
  // this is not as I expected. The keys are correct, however their values are all the same ArrayBuffer
```

Comment: Do you really need all this amount of mutability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: `withDefaultValue` is useless here.

Note the [signature of `withDefaultValue`](https://dotty.epfl.ch/api/scala/collection/mutable/HashMap.html#withDefaultValue-fffff3df) is:

```
def withDefaultValue(d: V): Map[K, V]
```

The parameter `d` is taken by value, not [by name](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html) (`=> V`), therefore it is **only evaluated once**. Therefore any key not present in the original map will return the same empty buffer you created once.

And what you get `withDefaultValue` (and `withDefault`) is a new map-like object, not the original map. Only assigning the results (`m("a") = ...`) will change it.

> Note: The default is only used for apply. Other methods like get, contains, iterator, keys, etc. are not affected by withDefaultValue.

Consider this example:

```
val m = new HashMap[Integer, Buffer[String]]()
val mm = m.withDefault(_ => Buffer.empty)
mm(1).append("4")
mm(1) // ArrayBuffer()
```

What you probably want is [`getOrElseUpdate`](https://dotty.epfl.ch/api/scala/collection/mutable/HashMap.html#getOrElseUpdate-fffff230) (you can define a helper function if you'd like) with the signature

```
getOrElseUpdate(key: K, defaultValue: => V): V
```

Note how `defaultValue` is called by name this time, and each call will create a new buffer:

```
val m: mutable.Map[String, mutable.Buffer[Int]] =
    mutable.HashMap.empty

def mm(key: String): mutable.Buffer[Int] = m.getOrElseUpdate(key, mutable.Buffer.empty)

mm("a") += 1
mm("b") += 2
// now buffers at `a` and `b` are distinct
```